# dell laser mouse working strangely

Tags: mouse, dell-xps

The left click on the mouse is behaving weird. It stopped working entirely, but now it does work on most the time; It still does not work on specific buttons, such as being able to open a tab in Chrome, but not being able to click the close button. Usually it fails in buttons that are not a part of a window.

edit: It goes back and forth from this state and functioning normally.

Comment: Do you have another mouse to test? Or another computer to test the Dell mouse on?

Comment: Is this a wireless mouse? If so maybe the receiver is too far away or defective. Does the receiver work better via other USB ports or if it's the only device plugged in?

Comment: it is not wireless